# vba json read sub array how to read

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

API using get it bellow json data

```
[{
"Id":"8",
"Date":"12/11/2018",


"readings":[{"Id":"61","DailyLogBookID":"8","Substation":"MS-1","LoadMax":"898","LoadMin":"9898","VoltageMax":"98","VoltageMin":"98","FrequencyMax":"988","FrequencyMin":"9898","PFMax":"988","PFMin":"989","PowerDip":"9898","Remarks":"9898"},

{"Id":"62","DailyLogBookID":"8","Substation":"MS-2","LoadMax":"9889","LoadMin":"98","VoltageMax":"98","VoltageMin":"889","FrequencyMax":"9898","FrequencyMin":"98","PFMax":"98","PFMin":"98","PowerDip":"98","Remarks":"98"}  
]}]

/*************VBA Code************/

Sub CallChildDate(id As String) 
Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i, j As Integer 
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 
Dim strUrl As String 
http.Open "GET", id, False 
http.send 
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText) 
i = 1 

For Each item In JSON
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = item("Id") 
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = item("Date")
i = i + 1 
Next

End Sub
```

How to get it above  "readings" data get assign in cell value. how to "readings" array data get for each using assn in cell.

Comment: What have you done so far?  A good place to start is here:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: I have assign above  json value assign variable "JSON"
For Each Item In JSON
 For i = 1 To 10
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("readings")(i)("Id") 
Next i
 Next
But Not working, sub json array how to get it.

Comment: If you have code, edit your question to add it.  Code in comments is not very readable.  "Not working" also needs some explanation - does it error?  If Yes what error do you get?

Comment: Hi have change my questions

Comment: should be easier to connect to the JSON file with Excel Power Query https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-json-file-f65207ab-d957-4bf0-bec3-a08bb53cd4c0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I note you have now edited the JSON and the question somewhat:

From your prior question: You were almost there. Below I am reading the JSON in from a file.

The `{` means a dictionary so you access by key, the `[` means a collection so you access by index.  `""` means a string literal so you read as is. I use a [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to handle the JSON read in from file. After adding the `.bas` from that link to your project you then add a reference via VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

If you examine the JSON structure to see where the `id`s within `readings` are you will see the initial object is a collection. `readings` is in the first item of that collection which is a dictionary. `readings` is the key that returns an collection of dictionaries:

```
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)(1)("readings")
```

So, you are looping over a collection of dictionaries in the code below where each `item` is a dictionary. You can the loop the dictionary keys and access and use the key (e.g. `id`) for each dictionary within to retrieve the associated value.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReadValues()
    Dim fso As Object, stream As Object, jsonText As String, item As Object
    Dim json As Object, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\HarrisQ\Desktop\test.json", ForReading)
    jsonText = stream.ReadAll
    stream.Close

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)(1)("readings") 'Collection of dictionaries

    Dim c As Long, key As Variant, arr(), r As Long

    With ws
        arr() = json(1).keys
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
        r = 2
        For Each item In json
            c = 1
            For Each key In item
                .Cells(r, c).Value = item(key)
                c = c + 1
            Next
            r = r + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**With your revised question:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CallChildDate(id As String)
    Dim json As Object, item As Object, ws As Worksheet, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", id, False  '<==Assuming id is actually a URL and not to be concantenated with your former variable strURL.
       .send
       Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)(1)("readings") 'Collection of dictionaries
    End With

    Dim c As Long, key As Variant, arr(), r As Long

    With ws
        arr() = json(1).keys
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
        r = 2
        For Each item In json
            c = 1
            For Each key In item
                .Cells(r, c).Value = item(key)
                c = c + 1
            Next
            r = r + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### Output using your initial JSON string:

[image]

Comment: i am not working in json file i'm working in api data get abow json data your code not working. "ParseJson(jsonText)(1)("readings")" Error now.

Comment: how to get in sub array is more then array list. how to working now.

Comment: You haven't included the rest of your code so I have had to read your JSON from file. You would have a line that read something like  Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)(1)("readings")    or xmlhttpobject.responseText   (what ever variable is holding the xmlhttp object if using XHR request.)

Comment: _how to get in sub array is more then array list. how to working now_  what does that mean? My code writes all the ids out to the sheet. To get every item in the inner dictionaries simply loop all the keys.